# python / pandas copy filename

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to automate some data cleaning I am doing using pandas.

I have a few separate .csv files in one folder. I want to read all these csv files into a dataframe, then create an `ID` column to the df where the values would be the name of each csv file.

Say the following files are read using glob:
1.csv 
2.csv 
3.csv

```
rawfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
tempframe = []
for file_ in rawfiles: 
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, header=0)
    tempframe.append(df)
```

but before concatenating them all into one dataframe, I want to add an `ID` column and have the name of each file as its value (i.e, `1`, `2`, `3` etc)

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Misread your question.  I'm setting ID equal to the name of each file minus the last 4 characters (.csv)

```
rawfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
tempframe = []
for file_ in rawfiles:  
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, header=0)
    df["ID"] = file_[:-4] 
    tempframe.append(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But wouldn't adding that make the entire ID column "1" regardless of filename?  - will try it and see what happens.

Cheers.